# Get files names from AjaxFileUpload Control on button click

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Please help with these ;

I have a gridview with AjaxFileupload in the Itemtemplate. After populating the gridview and uploading files using the AjaxFileUpload in each row. I need to read through the gridview and get the filename at bujtton click. Please find below the codes

```
<div>
<asp:GridView ID="grdView_Requirement" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Font-Names="Segoe UI" Font-Size="12px">
   <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Upload File">
               <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUploadNew" runat="server" Font-Names="Segoe    
                   UI" Font-Size="12px" MaximumNumberOfFiles="1" Width="388px" />
               </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
   </Columns>
  <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" ForeColor="#333333" />
  <HeaderStyle BackColor="#D7D9E5" ForeColor="#333333" />
  <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFFFF" ForeColor="#333333" />
  </asp:GridView>
</div>

   <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

Upload code

```
protected void AjaxFileUploadNew_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
       string strLongFilePath = e.FileName;
       string strFileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(strLongFilePath);
       char[] ch = new char[] { '\\' };
       string[] strPath = strLongFilePath.Split(ch);
       string strInternalFileName = DateTime.Now.ToFileTime().ToString() + strFileExtension;
       string strDestPath = Server.MapPath("~/UploaderTemp/");
       AjaxFileUploadNew.SaveAs(@strDestPath + strInternalFileName);
       //Save path, filename to database here
     }
```

Kindly help in getting the uploaded file name in the event below

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  foreach (GridViewRow row in grdView_Requirement.Rows)
    {
      //for bound field
      string str = row.Cells[0].Text.ToString();         
      //for templated control
      AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUpload tb = row.FindControl("AjaxFileUploadNew") as   
      AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUpload;
    }
 }
```

Kindly help resolve or give better ways of implementing to achieve success.

Comment: Can you explain what purpose are you trying to accomplish by getting those names? May be you can retrieve it from the Database where you just stored.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I want to recall the file name so as to store the file in a table with other associated data (i.e name) linked to it, as they are in the gridview. I want to ensure i can still link the stored files with its corresponding name. I hope my explanation is clear.

Comment: A better explanation: I have a gridview with two columns ( Name | Upload file) and a table PersonalUploadtbl in my database with 3 columns ( Id | Name | File( varbinaryMAX) ).
I tried adding the insert method to the db table PersonalUploadtbl in the AjaxFileUploadNew_UploadComplete event; but I couldnt access the other row data (i.e name) in the event.So I decided to add an extra button that would read through all rows in the gridview after upload has been done and get the corresponding name and filename of the uploaded file so I can save it into the database table PersonalUploadtbl .

Comment: Check this: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Upload-Files-Asynchronously-829691df